# Syncing a custom made(PHP) calendar with iCal/Google calendar?

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I developed a calendar on my intranet using PHP, it exports a "*.ics" file that can be imported to iCal and Google calendar. But the project sponsor requires that the calendar auto sync with iCal/Google cal, I'm not sure if it's possible, or how to do it. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export google calendar content into a special XML file through a public URL. All you have to do is to periodically synchronize your calendar data with the online data.

Check this url:

[Exporting google calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37103?hl=en)

Alternatively you could check out other, already working implementations.

Here is a nice tutorial:

[Goole Celendar API Guide for PHP](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_php)

Also, have a look at this question:

[Another Stackoverflow question in the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603888/google-calendar-sync-with-php-in-2-ways)